# Best software to build charts (pies, bars)

Tags: charts

I am somewhat disappointed with Excel charts and short of building my own with a vector graphics too, is there something really awesome for charts?

Comment: Just so we know what we're looking for in terms of demands, could you explain in what way Excel dissapointed you when it comes to building chards ?

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: The fact that he mentions Excel means he probably uses Windows.

Comment: I am good with Linux & Windows

Comment: Excel does not allow to customize in sufficient detail location of labels, styles of legend, etc. The basic pie/chart is agreeable

Answer (score 2):

For high end stuff you can use gnuplot, R, or scilab.  Will have a steep learning curve, but the end results are generally better for technical publications.

Comment: gnuplot is actually better at plots, but for charts I'd go for Excel anyday. ... I haven't used R or scilab, so cal't judge those.

Comment: R is generally used for statistical analysis and the graphics to go with it. http://www.r-project.org/  Scilab is much similar to Mathematica. http://www.scilab.org/

Answer (score 1):

Numbers (part of iWork of Apple) beats Excel graphs and pies hands down every day of the week.